# SFService is a 'namespace' but is used like a type

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, salesforce

I'm trying to accomplishing a simple task of validating a SessionID (that I already have) through the SOAP API of SalesForce. Problem is, all the examples I found on internet is like this:

`SforceService binding = new SforceService();`

`binding.Url = serverUrl;`

`binding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();`
`binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = sessionId;`

but for the very first line doesn't work for me, I've added the web reference through Visual Studio and WSDL file that I've downloaded through my account on salesforce. but SforceService is a namespace that can't be instantiated.

this is how my Solution Explorer looks like after adding the reference:
[image]

All I want to is to validate a SessionID!!

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added a service reference, not a web reference, you need to go through the advanced button and pick web reference instead. (Or you should be able to get it to work with a service reference, but the programming model is different, so the samples you're looking at don't apply)

Comment: Going through Advanced button needs a URL, and What I have is this:
https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/28.0 

which obviously needs to do the whole login process, am I right? is there a way to just validate the sessionID ? or I have to login?

Comment: and even when I do that it says Get not supported.

Comment: you can use a file:// reference in the add web reference dialog.

Comment: I did as u said, still I cannot create an instance of the service.
so this line throws an error:
<code>SforceService binding = new SforceService();</code>

Comment: What's the error? did you add an import statement for the namespace you gave the WSDL?

Comment: here is the error: 'SFService' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'
is a typical error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I just had to add sforce namespace to my file (import it). Thanks to @Superfell